# Refactor a constructor in Java with Intellij

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, constructor

I'm refactoring my java code with IntelliJ and need to add an extra parameter on a constructor.

Let's say I'm editing the class SocialNetwork and just changed how I add a friend, instead of just a name now the class also has an Integer that is the age.

Of course IntelliJ will tell me the constructor doesn't exist. So far so good.

Now the problem, on Eclipse it is possible to choose among create a new constructor or change the existing one. When I hit `Alt`+`Enter` on IntelliJ I only get the option to create a new constructor.

Is there a way for IntelliJ for offer the option do add an Integer parameter to the existing constructor?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intellij treats constructors just like regular methods, so the same refactoring procedures apply to constructors (save for a few caveats, like editing the name)

You can use `Refactor -> Change Signature...` to add and remove parameters, by accessing either from the definition, or any statement that uses `new`

[image]

Comment: For clarification, is this option available at the ctor definition, the instantiation with `new`, or both?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I updated the answer, turns out you can!

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I still think that the Eclipse approach is easier on this feature, but I don't think it's a big deal to this way ;-)